# no. of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$

Tags: combinatorics

If  $\bf{L.C.M}$ of $(a,b)$ is $432$ and $\bf{L.C.M}$ of $(b,c)$ is ${72}$ and $\bf{L.C.M}$
$(c,a)$ is $324$.

Then no. of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ is.

$\underline{\bf{My\;Try}}$:: Given $\bf{L.C.M}$ of $(a,b) = 472 = 2^4\cdot 3^3$

and Given $\bf{L.C.M}$ of $(b,c) = 72 = 2^3\cdot 3^2$

Given $\bf{L.C.M}$ of $(c,a) = 324 = 2^2\cdot 3^4$

So Let we take $a = 2^{x_{1}}\cdot 3^{y_{1}}$ and $a = 2^{x_{2}}\cdot 3^{y_{2}}$ and $a = 2^{x_{3}}\cdot 3^{y_{3}}$.

Now I did not understand How can i proceed further

please help me , Thanks

Comment: this usage of bold and uppercase characters, underlines, dots and :: does not improve the appearance and the readibility  of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every  number is the product of prime powers of $2$ and $3$. To investigat a primepower (e.g. the powers of $2$) 
I constructed the following table

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|ccc}
n&a&b&c&a,b&b,c&a,c\\
\hline
1&1&2&3&2&3&3\\
2&1&3&2&3&3&2\\
3&2&1&3&2&3&3\\
4&2&3&1&3&3&2\\
5&3&1&2&3&2&3\\
6&3&2&1&3&2&3\\
\hline
7&1&2&2&2&2&2\\
8&2&1&2&2&2&2\\
9&2&2&1&2&2&2\\
\hline
10&1&1&2&1&2&2\\
11&1&2&1&2&2&1\\
12&2&1&1&2&1&2\\
\hline
13&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\end{array}
$$
The first column is simply the line number.
The meaning of line 1: if the exponent of $2$ in $a$ is the smallest(1), the exponent of $2$ in $b$ is the second smallest (2) and the exponent of $2$ in $c$ is the third smallest (3) (this means the largest) then the exponent of $2$ in $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ is the second smallest (2). The exponent of $2$ in $\text{lcm}(b,c)$ and $\text{lcm}(a,c)$ is the largest (3). Line 1 to 6 show the outcome of this reasoning for all possible permutations of the exponents if the three exponents are different. Line 7 to 9 show the result if the two larger exponents are equal and 10 to 12 if the two lower exponents are equal. 13 show the result if all exponents are equal.

Which of these 13 lines are valid in  your example for the exponents of $2$?

Comment: Thanks miracle173...............

Answer (score 2):

There are no such triples.

When ${\rm lcm}(a,b)=432=2^4\cdot 3^3$ then concerning the prime $3$ the number $a$ is divisible by at most  $3^3$, and when ${\rm lcm}(b,c)=72=2^3\cdot 3^2$ then concerning the prime $3$ the number $c$ is divisible by at most $3^2$. It follows that ${\rm lcm}(a,c)$ contains at most a factor $3^3$, and not $3^4$ as requested by ${\rm lcm}(a,c)=324$.

Comment: Thanks Christian Blatter.......

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $(a,b,c)$ is an ordered triplet.  Given LCM of $(a,b)=432=2^4\cdot3^3$ you must have one of $a,b$ has a factor of $2^4$ and the other has at most four powers of two, and one of $a,b$ must have a factor of $3^3$ and the other has at most three powers of three.  It can't be the same one, as one of the other two LCMs would have to be at least $432$, so you have two possibilities:  $16 | a$ or $16 | b$.  You can rule out one of them using another LCM.  Similarly, you can determine which of $a,b$ is divisible by $27$.

Comment: You do mean $2^43^3$ and not $2^4 + 3^3$, right?

Comment: @DennisMeng:  Yes, typo fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ross Milikan............